# Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Prerendering failed because of error: ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular2-aot, angular-universal

I am using Angular components in Angular universal sample.

My Angular components are wrapper of java script widget and widget uses `window.jquery`to render control.

when m importing my Angular components m facing issue like below.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>             Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Prerendering failed 
>                because of error: ReferenceError: window is not defined
>              at Object. (E:\Incident sample\130606\aspnetcore-angular2-
>                universal-master\Client\dist\main-server.js:30544:9)
>                 at Object. (E:\Incident sample\130606\aspnetcore-
>                     angular2-universal-master\Client\dist\main-server.js:30545:3)
>                    at **webpack_require** (E:\Incident sample\130606\aspnetcore-
>                        angular2-universal-master\Client\dist\main-server.js:26:30)
>                 at Object. (E:\Incident sample\130606\aspnetcore-
>                  angular2-universal-master\Client\dist\main-server.js:19344:2)

Any one help me to find out issue.

But m seeing window is not supported in Angular universal . Anyway to use these angular components?

Thanks !!

Answer (score -1):

You can use HostListener Decorator instead of windows it will give you same feel like windows event

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/HostListener-interface.html

checkout above link and you will have better idea.

Also it is best practice to use HostListener instead of windows

This is for more details

https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/custom-directives/hostlistener-and-hostbinding/

Hope this helps